# Interpolating a non-continuous set of points

Tags: interpolation, plotting

I'm trying to create a pure function that I can feed into *OutputResponse[ ]* as the input *u[t]*. In order to do this, I've written code to create a square wave pulse train in the form of a collection of (x,y) points. This is created from two lists: a list of y values ("vVect") and a list of x values ("tVect"). In trying to use *Interpolation[ ]* (and *ListInterpolation[ ]*), I am getting back functions that behave different than the set of points they interpolate. Is this just a problem with Mathematica's plotting function? What I want is something that looks exactly like the ListLinePlot, but that I can assign to the function *u*, as I can't pass a set of points to *OutputResponse[ ]*.

```
pTrain = Partition[Riffle[tVect, vVect], 2];     
ListLinePlot[pTrain]
```

[image: ListLinePlot]

```
u = ListInterpolation[vVect, {{0, 0.002}}, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
Plot[u[t], {t, 0, 0.002}]
```

[image: Plot of interpolation function]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Please provide at a manageable portion of `tVect` and `cVect`, so that your computations can be reproduced.

Comment: Sorry!
tVect:<https://www.dropbox.com/s/2pqygz5sfc030o1/tVect.dat?dl=0>
vVect:
<https://www.dropbox.com/s/7nuws5kusoxaxrn/vVect.dat?dl=0>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need more  PlotPoints:

```
tVect = Get["tVect.dat"] ;
vVect = Get["vVect.dat"] ;
pTrain = Partition[Riffle[tVect, vVect], 2];
f = Interpolation[pTrain, InterpolationOrder -> 0] ;
Plot[f[s], Evaluate[Join[{s}, First[f["Domain"]]]], PlotPoints -> 200]
```